# Mangle page content from browserSync's server

Tags: javascript, server, browser-sync

In [browserSync](https://browsersync.io/)'s server I can define a middleware to mangle responses. For header values I can do it like this:

```js
    browserSync.init({
        ...
        middleware: [
            function (req, res, next) {
                if (req.url.split('.').pop()  === "jsp") {
                    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                }
                next();
            }
        ],
        ...
```

**Is there a way to mangle the response *content* as well (e.g. via regexes or similar)?**

*Note:* In my particular case I want to remove all text between `<%` and `%>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [rewrite rules](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-rewriteRules)

```
rewriteRules: [
    {
        match: /<%[^%]*%>/g,
        replace: ""
    }
]
```